# Codeigniter active record CASE working in select but can't order by its parameters

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord, sql-order-by, case

I have following select in my model:

```
$this->db->select("*, product.id as id, product.price as price, attribute.price as att_price, CASE WHEN(attribute.price > 0) THEN attribute.price ELSE product.price END as newprice");
```

When I fetch the results I can echo `$product->newprice` and it works well. The problem is that I want to order results by product price or attribute price if it exist. I can easy make it work by using similar `CASE` in `order_by()`. But instead I want to skip it and use `newprice` there.

When I try `$this->db->order_by("newprice ASC")` I get the **following error:**

> Error Number: 105
>
> Unknown column 'newprice' in 'where clause'

I can't understand why I can't use `newprice` in the order by function, but I have newprice when I fetch the results.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `CASE WHEN` statement in **()** as below, put whole query in temp:

```
$this->db->select("(*, product.id as id, product.price as price, attribute.price as att_price, (CASE WHEN(attribute.price > 0)                   
THEN attribute.price ELSE product.price END;) as newprice) as temp");
$this->db->order_by("temp.newprice ASC")
```